# jquery Element to DOM Element returns empty string by function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this code:

```
function fn(el){ return $(el)[0].style.width };
fn('#someElementIdId');  // return -> ""
```

But this code...

```
function fn(el){ return $(el).width() } ;
fn('#someElement');  // return -> correct width
```

I have tried different things, but all have the same result...

How can I make the first code work?

**CODE HERE :: http://jsfiddle.net/A2VpH/18/**

Comment: From the docs for `.width()`: *Get the current **computed** width for the first element in the set of matched elements.* `.style.width` gets the width set in the CSS. It is not the same. I suggest to have a look at the implementation of `.width()`.

Comment: Just a quick sanity check, `fn('#someElementIdId');` and `fn('#someElement');` reference different objects. In your code the ID's are the same?

Comment: ".style.width gets the width set in the CSS".... sorry is incorrect ... note that css props. is setup here >> jsfiddle.net/A2VpH/18.... and dont works.... BUT if puts properties in TAGS like here >> jsfiddle.net/A2VpH/32 ..... ist's works..I THOUGHT SO....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, is there, and don't works... Any DOM's property properly set up
>   ... don't works. Make a REAL test for yourself

Here's a test showing jQuery vs regular DOM: http://jsfiddle.net/A2VpH/3/

Works fine for me.

Comment: Esailija.... thank you for your effort... 

But how make works that CODE .... the properties is there in CSS....

You don't call $("element")[0].DOM_any_property INSIDE a function, you set up OUTSIDE... is right ??

Comment: @Servius, I am sorry I cannot understand what are you saying. :( It doesn't make any difference whether you do it inside function. `.style.width` returns `""` because there is no style attribute set. You have to use `getComputedStyle` or `currentStyle` to get the real style that could be from CSS..

Comment: @Servius, I have updated to show that even jQuery returns `""` when you try to get the style property. http://jsfiddle.net/A2VpH/1/

Comment: @Servius, http://jsfiddle.net/A2VpH/6/. You were missing a `return` statement, as you can see it returns now an empty string, not `undefined`.. It is empty because it does entirely different thing than `.width()` which is demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: Here... sorry a forgot the return... http://jsfiddle.net/A2VpH/12/.... but this dont care... dont works !!! return a empty string...

Comment: ESAILIJA :: Like i UPDATED the  question :: Better code here :: http://jsfiddle.net/A2VpH/18/ ... THIS DON'T WORKS.... but yours code works, cos you parse jquery element into DOM element OUTSIDE function.... but my code NOT

Comment: @Servius, for the 55th time, `.style.width` does not do what `width()` does. See here with almost exact same code: http://jsfiddle.net/A2VpH/23/

Comment: Only a parentheses :: if i call a jquery function to modify any properties, then "css properties" =getComputedStyle and WORKS like this >> jsfiddle.net/A2VpH/27 or if i set properties in TAGS like this >> jsfiddle.net/A2VpH/32 WORKS TOO.... but if set properties in CSS like this >> DONT WORKS......THIS CREATES A MESS

Answer (score 0):

You can use offsetWidth, clientWidth, or a currentStyle/getComputedStyle hybrid depending on your browser:

**HTML**

```
<div id="someElementIdId"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
 width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
   border: 5px solid black; 
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function getStyle(x,styleProp)
{
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}

function fn1(el){ return $(el)[0].currentStyle.width; };

function fn2(el){ return $(el).width(); };

function fn3(el){ return getStyle($(el)[0],'width').replace('px', ''); };

function fn4(el){ return $(el)[0].offsetWidth; };

function fn5(el){ return $(el)[0].clientWidth; };

alert( fn3('#someElementIdId') );
```

Note that offsetWidth will include the padding, scrollBar, and the border. If you want width + padding you can use clientWidth.

It also might help to know why you want to do this? If you are going to be using jQuery to find the element in the DOM why not use the jQuery width() function as well?

http://jsfiddle.net/A2VpH/24/

Comment: `.width()` doesn't include padding or border, `offsetWidth` includes both padding and border.

Comment: "It also might help to know why you want to do this? If you are going to be using jQuery to find the element in the DOM why not use the jQuery width() function as well?"...........:: Besides the the behavior javascript confused me ....Cos i hates read properties in parenthesis, what is more readable  ?  el[0].style.width = 300 ...............or......... el.width( "300")  ...?.... matter of aesthetics...

Comment: David... thank you... and sorry... i don't saw your answer before... it's correct .... i was entertained with Esailija.... THE MESS is because getComputedStyle is different to "css style", depending to context........... ::: read the final comment above

Answer (score 0):

The "style" attribute does not contain **all** the style information for an element. It's just the stuff that's there directly in the tag, like:

```
<div style='width: 100px'>
```

If the width comes from CSS, it won't be there.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I saw at a glance, I thought you was referring to the CSS, not the tag